# Next.js rewrite with x headers

Tags: javascript, nginx, next.js, http-headers

I have a web app where users can build their own profiles with their usernames like below.

```
ourplatform.com/john
ourplatform.com/john/about
ourplatform.com/john/contact

ourplatform.com/jane
ourplatform.com/jane/about
ourplatform.com/jane/contact
```

They can also connect their domains so they have to be using like this.

```
john.com
john.com/about
john.com/contact

jane.com
jane.com/about
jane.com/contact
```

This is my `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites () {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'header',
            key: 'x-username',
            value: '(?<username>.*)'
          }
        ],
        destination: '/:username/:path*'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the Nginx configuration.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name john.com;

  add_header x-username "john";
  proxy_set_header x-username "john";

  location /_next {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1323;
  }

  location = / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1323/john;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1323/john$request_uri;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting 404 issue on the domains. What's wrong with the current setup?

Comment: 404 means not found, what is exactly was not found, according to your `access.log` and `error.log`?

Comment: Actually nothing show up in both of those files. Because this is not an Nginx issue. I just see the default `404 This page could not be found.` error of Next.js. In the network tab of Chrome all the files in /_next folder are loading successfully. It's just the main `/` path has a problem. Feels like something wrong with the rewrite config.

Comment: ok, but how we could know what is actual reason without watching logs or debugging your rewrite rule? Also, why is this issue tagged `nginx` if you consider it not a nginx problem?

Comment: At this point I have no idea. Could be Nginx, could be Next.js. I was thinking maybe someone experienced with both of those could show me a way or maybe give an example code to achieve this problem. Don't know what to do. Whole system depend on this so I need to find a way.

Answer (score 2):

host matching might be an alternative approach as explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#header-cookie-and-query-matching)

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'john.com' }],
        destination: '/john/:path*',
      },
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'jane.com' }],
        destination: '/jane/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```